# How to call the two points at each end of a path?

Tags: phrases, expressions

By "path" I mean a *route that has been walked by*.

The best I could come out with is *starting point* and *ending point*.

Is there a shorter way to refer to them?

(Maybe end points?)

Comment: Yes, *end points*, or just *ends* if they are at the ends of the route; maybe even *termini*: the last or final part or point; either end of a railway, bus route, etc, or a station or town at such a point; a goal aimed for ... (Collins)

Comment: beginning & end

Comment: not sure of your exact usage needs, but *the start and finish* or *from start to finish* (if you really are getting at what happens all along the path) might fit, or just *both ends of the path*

Comment: *Source & Destination* - These words are often used in computer science to refer to the starting and ending nodes of a path.

Comment: Maybe (or maybe not) duplicate of [Word for an Origin and Destination without regard for route](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125178/word-for-an-origin-and-destination-without-regard-for-route) and also see [A word for the beginning of a street?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111498)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to them as *terminal points* or just *terminals* if you want something shorter.

Some transit systems refer to the train stop at the end of a line as the *Terminal* station, meaning that there are no more stations after this point, and the train just turns around and goes back the other way.

Comment: Or you could use the Latin word _terminus_ (pl _termini_, if you want to be fussy), which refers to either end of a line or path. The starting point is the _terminus a quo_ 'terminus from which' and the ending point is the _terminus ad quem_ 'terminus toward which'.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply said *the ends of a path*, I think most people would understand that to encompass each end.

*Starting and ending points* assume a directionality, which may or may not be what you intend.